# How to have vertical stripes across whole object?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

I want to have vertical stripes across my sofa model like in the reference photo. I have used UV editing on object seams (the model is all one object) but the stripes on the arm of the sofa appear as horizontal. Any ideas on how to fix/make them vertical?
Thanks!

[image: blendersofa]

Comment: you need to rotate this part of your UV. Also please edit your post in order to display the image here

Comment: Thanks @moonboots I've edited the post and will try rotating UV :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in front orthographic view, you could select all in edit mode with A > press U > and click Project From View. Your UV will then appear the same as the object does in front view, so the Wave Texture will be vertical while using the UV Coordinates. You can use the Mapping node to change the scale of the stripes.

[image: Vertical Stripes using UC Coordinates]

Alternatively, you can use the Object Coordinates. If you haven't applied your object's rotation, you can use the Mapping node to rotate the stripes accordingly.

[image: Vertical stripes using Object Coordinates)]